# How to set auto-indent and formatting style in Atom.io editor

Tags: netbeans, package, code-formatting, atom-editor

I'm looking for a way to auto-format code in Atom.io, but so far I did not find anything useful in the forums...

I know other IDEs have this feature. For example in Netbeans there is a feature to auto-format code that is configurable (Tools>Options>Editor) in terms of style and language where you can fine-tune any aspect of formatting, such as spaces before keywords or parentheses, specific keyword indentation, tab size, indent size, braces placement and so on.

Is there anything similar in Atom.io, or is there a way to emulate, maybe only partially, this auto-format features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you check [Atom Beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) ?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I had to install also Uncrustify from the Ubuntu rep and download a [style file](https://gist.github.com/mkroman/1372117), but now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

my atom version is 1.8.0. In *keymap.cson*, I use this:

`'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-i': 'editor:auto-indent'`

Comment: It works fine! Also, `ctrl-shift-f` is possible to keep the same as Netbeans.